# How to catch CursorWindow errors

Tags: java, android-cursor

After my `ListView` has been already populated with `Cursor` results (method `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query`)  I get after several seconds (*not immediately*) this log:

```
04-08 07:40:43.501: E/CursorWindow(854): need to grow: mSize = 1048576, size = 54, freeSpace() = 12, numRows = 12129
04-08 07:40:43.501: E/CursorWindow(854): not growing since there are already 12129 row(s), max size 1048576
04-08 07:40:43.501: E/CursorWindow(854): The row failed, so back out the new row accounting from allocRowSlot 12128
04-08 07:40:43.501: E/Cursor(854): Failed allocating fieldDir at startPos 0 row 12128
04-08 07:40:43.950: D/Cursor(854): finish_program_and_get_row_count row 17368
```

The point is I cannot figure why I get this messages and from *what* place they come, since the results had been already loaded and the row count returned from database is only 470, but not 12129, as the log says. I suspect the message can come from other module of the app in some weird way because of intensive using of database queries.

The question is how can I trace back such `CursorWindow` errors, maybe by setting some global error handler etc., since I get for some reason this messages not immediately and cannot figure out what piece of code causes them.

Answer (score 0):

Always close cursor objects after use them. Then you can avoid such errors.

Comment: Thanks. I will check this suggestion and give feedback.